# Python: MSAL --> Getting token with username and password

Tags: python, azure, azure-active-directory, token, msal

I am following the [Microsoft documentation for aquiring an MSAL token by username and password](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/scenario-desktop-acquire-token-username-password?tabs=python).

For understanding how MSAL works I try something very simple: Aquiring a token using a username and password. Curly brackets ({}) in the below example represent IDs or credentials I have copied there.

```
authority_url = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{Tenant}’
app = msal.PublicClientApplication(
    authority=authority_url
    , client_id={client_id}'
    , client_credential=None
)

app.acquire_token_by_username_password(
    '{mail_of_windows_user}'
    , ‘{password_of_windows_user}’
    , scopes = ["User.Read"])
```

When I run the code I get an error with ID 7000218:

> The request body must contain the following parameter:
> 'client_assertion' or 'client_secret'.

This error is unexpected because a `PublicClientApplication` should work without a client secret. In the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/msal/msal.application.clientapplication?view=msal-py-latest) for the parameter `client_credential`, one can read:

> For PublicClientApplication, you simply use None here.

Why do I need a client secret even though the documentation states I need none?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The error usually occurs if you missed enabling **public-client flows** option while generating token using username password flow, which is **required** to recognize app registration as public client application.

Initially, I too got **same error** when I ran below code to generate access token without enabling *public-client flows* option:

```py
import msal

authority_url ='https://login.microsoftonline.com/{Tenant}’
app = msal.PublicClientApplication(
    authority=authority_url,
    client_id={client_id},
    client_credential=None
)
result = app.acquire_token_by_username_password(
    '{mail_of_windows_user}'
    , '{password_of_windows_user}'
    , scopes = ["User.Read"])

if "access_token" in result:
    access_token = result["access_token"]
    print(f"Access Token: {access_token}")
else:
    print(result.get('error_description'))
```

**Response:**

[image]

To resolve the error, make sure to enable **public-client flows** option in your app registration like this:

[image]

When I ran code again after enabling *public-client flows* without passing client secret, I got **access token** successfully in response:

```py
import msal

authority_url ='https://login.microsoftonline.com/{Tenant}’
app = msal.PublicClientApplication(
    authority=authority_url,
    client_id={client_id},
    client_credential=None
)
result = app.acquire_token_by_username_password(
    '{mail_of_windows_user}'
    , '{password_of_windows_user}'
    , scopes = ["User.Read"])

if "access_token" in result:
    access_token = result["access_token"]
    print(f"Access Token: {access_token}")
else:
    print(result.get('error_description'))
```

**Response:**

[image]

You can decode the above token in [jwt.ms](https://jwt.ms) and check whether the claims are **valid** or not like this:

[image]

**Reference:**
[Microsoft identity platform and OAuth 2.0 Resource Owner Password Credentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/v2-oauth-ropc#authorization-request)